# How to test response of service using mock?

Tags: python, json, unit-testing, service, mocking

I have the following service with a post request:

```
import requests

class Attt():
    def get_req(self):
        pload = {'username': 'Olivia', 'password': '123'}
        r = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data=pload)
        print(r.text)
        print(r.content)


obj=Attt()
obj.get_req()
```

I would like to mock the request so that I can create the needed response of the service.
I have written a test like below:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from mock_tutorial.attt import Attt
import pandas as pd

class TestMockService(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_mock(self):

        fake_json = [{'test': "mock"}]

        with patch('mock_tutorial.attt.requests.post') as mock_get:
            mock_get.return_value.status_code = 200
            mock_get.return_value.json.return_value = fake_json

            obj = Attt()
            response = obj.get_req()
            print('response json', response.json())

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(response.json(), fake_json)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

But as the `get_req` method doesn't return the reesponse, the assertions fail: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'json'`. How can I modify the assertions to check that the response of the get_req method has been mocked correspondingly, to the fake_json variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are not returning anything from `Attt.get_req` thus it returns `None`. So in your test, it is like calling `None.json()`. You should return the response of the request:

```
...
class Attt():
    def get_req(self):
        ...
        return r
...
```

Also as documented, you should wrap your code in *attt.py* so that it doesn't get executed when imported:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj=Attt()
    obj.get_req()
```

This seems fine since this is just for tutorial. But take note that there are already libraries you can use that mocks the `requests` module such as [requests-mock](https://pypi.org/project/requests-mock/).

---

**Update**

If the method wouldn't return anything, then all we can do to check is by adding a spy to the target functionality. But take note that this wouldn't make sense in reality because what we are spying on is a mocked/patched functionality which is `requests.post`. This would only be good for learning purposes but in reality, better yet not add the test as it doesn't add any value at all. We can use [pytest-mock](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/) for this purpose:

**mock_tutorial/attt.py**

```
import requests

class Attt():
    def get_req(self):
        pload = {'username': 'Olivia', 'password': '123'}
        r = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data=pload)
        print(r.text)
        print(r.content)
```

**test_attt.py**

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from mock_tutorial import attt
from mock_tutorial.attt import Attt

import pytest


def test_mock(mocker):  # Run <pip install pytest-mock>
    fake_json = [{'test': "mock"}]

    with patch('mock_tutorial.attt.requests.post') as mock_get:
        mock_get.return_value.status_code = 200
        mock_get.return_value.json.return_value = fake_json

        post_spy = mocker.spy(attt.requests, "post")

        obj = Attt()
        response = obj.get_req()

        assert post_spy.spy_return.status_code == 200
        assert post_spy.spy_return.json() == fake_json
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there an option to solve the failing assertions without returning the response value?

Comment: With those assertions? No there is no other option. Because the assertions check the response of the method `self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)` where `response` is from the return of the method `response = obj.get_req()`. If you really don't intend to return anything and still want to test the call, then you should implement a spy as in this [library](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/).

Comment: Unless you are open to mocking `Attt.get_req()` too? As we can mock its return value so that it doesn't return `None`. But I think such test doesn't make sense anymore as everything would just be mocked :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I was wondering if it is possible to let ```get_req``` without it returning the response and to find a way to change the current assertions, so that they can check the response has been changed to the ```fake_json```

Comment: @IanKurtis I updated my answer on how you could spy on the `requests.post` and check the return. Does it answer your question now?